# Securely remove data from hard drive without killing recovery partition

Tags: data-recovery, deletion

Information Security vs Business question here:

IT department asks me for a way to securely remove data from a hard drive because they want to sell old hardware.

I suggest DBAN as a secure wipe tool.

Problem: DBAN will remove every partition / hard drive it comes across including the recovery partition.

Question: is there a way to remove data from the "work" partition in a secure way while keeping the recovery partition?

Comment: Alright, so I don't know whether this would work- so **don't** do it- but... Open question to the room: Would something along the lines of `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda1` cut it, provided `/dev/sda` is the primary drive, `/dev/sda1` is the primary partition, and `/dev/sda2` is the recovery partition? Or is that not how that works?

Comment: I'm relatively certain that dban can wipe individual partitions.  The autonuke feature deletes the whole disk, but I believe you can configure it to only delete the partitions you like.

Comment: @SteveSether can you name the option specifically, because I am not familiar with this option, as far as I know DBAN does not offer partition wipe

Comment: @ParthianShot apparently that should be quite secure, see http://superuser.com/questions/118439/how-secure-is-dd-if-dev-urandom-of-dev-sda

Comment: @user3244085 Well, sure. I'm just not sure whether it would corrupt the partition table or something awful like that. He wants the recovery partition to remain bootable.

Comment: I know you asked about securely wiping a drive partition but why not: 1. clone the recovery partition to another drive. 2. wipe/nuke drive repeatedly. 3. clone recovery partition back on.

Answer (score 1):

Disks do not always map a logical address to the same physical location, especially SSDs. When a remap has happened, the physical location with data may not even be accessible to user programs like DBAN. Specialised make/model-specific tool will be required and they most often can only do full wipes.

So the only *real* safe solution is to clone the recovery parition to a new drive and destroy the old one. Of course whether you do this depends on how sensitive/valuable the data is and what kind of potential threats you want to defend against.

A more economical workaround is to clone the recovery parition (and partition table/MBR) to another media, fully wipe the original using the correct tool and clone the partition back.